# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los descendientes de una ventana?

Tags: c#, lua

Básicamente lo que estoy tratando de hacer, es obtener todos los hijos de los hijos de los hijos..., En lua esto es fácil de hacer, solo usas GetDescendants().
Quiero obtener todos los textbox de mi programa, pero no sé hacerlo, solo sé obtener los hijos de un objeto, pero no todos sus descendientes.

En lua sería algo así:

```
for i, obj  in pairs(Frame:GetDescendants)do
     if(obj:IsA("Textbox"))then
           Textbox.Text = "Hola";
     end
end
``
```

Comment: 2 cosas: ¿Qué has investigado? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: He investigado la manera de obtener todos los hijos, pero no los descendientes de los hijos porque no encuentro información.   foreach(Control i in panel1.Controls)

Comment: Incluye todos esos intentos y de ese modo, incrementas la chance de obtener respuestas porque se respetan los lineamientos del sitio. Aquí unas recomendaciones generales: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822. Saludos :D